# var_dump($_POST) пустой при XMLHttpRequest POST отправке

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

Есть код:

```
$( "#form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = $(this).serializeArray();//или serialize()
    xhr.open('POST', '******.php', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form- 
                          urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(formData);
    console.log( formData );
    }
```

в консоли: 
          `(2) [{…}, {…}]
           0: {name: "address", value: "da"}
           1: {name: "email", value: "net"}
           length: 2
   XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/***.loc/***.php".`

вывожу в файл.php через var_dump($_POST) данные: array(0) {   } пусто
причем ***.php срабатывает на success, ощущение что сервер работает, но не желает отображать post data!?
за неделю обчитался всего уже: делал parse_str($_POST['formData'], $formData);
нашел что xhr.send(formData) должен передавать пару ключ - значение, но я так понимаю что POST передает всегда string, a parse_str переводит в массив данных  с ключами и значениями.
Новичок))))) в ступоре. Научите пжлста!!!! как на стороне сервера отразить 
XMLHttpRequest POST данные (AJAX тоже самое) Спасибо!!!

Comment: а как понимаете что  var_dump($_POST) возвращает пустые данные? из кода этого не видно. И где вызов xhr.onreadystatechange ?

Comment: через xhr.onload = function(e) { if (xhr.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {window.open('файл.php','_blank','640','480');} а там array(0) { }

Comment: суть ajax запросов в том, что при запросе сервер отвечает вам, и этот ответ вы можете обработать. При window.open('файл.php','_blank','640','480'); вы делаете новый запрос на сервер не ajax, без всяких данных, поэтому там пусто.

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange: мне на клиентской стороне нужно потоково сгенерировать pdf из файл.php и открыть его в window.open, для  видныгенерации нужны в файл.php данные формы...все сделал но данные не

Comment: window.open('файл.php','_blank','640','480') - эта команда говорит браузеру открой мне окно размером 640x480 и отрази в нём результат работы скрипта файл.php. здесь нет аякса, и данные в этот момент скрипту не передаются

Comment: точно, просто я по шаблону с http://www.alexhadik.com/blog/2016/7/7/l8ztp8kr5lbctf5qns4l8t3646npqh генерирую pdf но он все время пустой...как же все-таки увидеть что на сервер приходит?

Comment: т.е. по ответу сервера (responseText) я могу увидеть, что он получил!!!

Comment: Спасибо Александр!т.е. мне перед отправкой данных, надо что-то с ними сделать чтоб увидел генератор на серверной стороне!?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос, чтобы на него ответить нужно больше информации о ней. Можете ниже отметить правильный ответ, чтобы помочь другим пользователи с такой же проблемой

Comment: если это зеленая галка , то отметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте такой код, чтобы получить post от сервера:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
xhr.open('POST', '******.php', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    // OK
    console.log( xhr.responseText );
  } else {
    // Обработать тут ошибку
  }
}
xhr.send(formData);
```